# Lisp recursion for split-list

Tags: recursion, split, lisp, common-lisp

```
(defun split-list (L) 
    (if (endp L)
    '(nil nil)  
     (let ((x (split-list (cdr L)))) 
         (list (cons (car L) (cadr x))(car X))
         )))
```

This is the code which I have. It works fine:

```
(split-list '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
((1 3 5) (2 4 6))
```

But I need an explanation on the recursion part.

When we call the function `(split-list (cdr L))` I am sure that it goes from 123456 to 23456. `(car L)` is 1 
and `(cadr X)` is 3 but how did 5 came there ?

when function did 
`(split-list (cdr L))` didn't the `x` became 3456 and `(cadr x)` should be 4 ? which is wrong and same with other half. `(car x)` should be 3 now which is wrong.

Could anyone please explain ?

Answer (score 4):

I would rewrite a recursive `split-list` as this:

```
(defun split-list (list) 
  (if (endp list)
      (values nil nil)
    (multiple-value-bind (split1 split2)
        (split-list (rest list))
      (values (cons (first list) split2)
              split1))))
```

Above uses multiple values. The function returns the split result as two values. We also replace `car` with `first` and `cdr` with `rest`. The are just better names, but have the same functionality. `multiple-value-bind` binds the the two values of the recursive `split-list` call to the variables `split1` and `split2`. The function `values` returns its two arguments as two values.

In the example below, you can see that the function indeed returns two values:

```
CL-USER 20 > (split-list '(a b c d e f))
(A C E)
(B D F)
```

You can trace its execution:

```
CL-USER 21 > (trace split-list)
(SPLIT-LIST)

CL-USER 22 > (split-list '(a b c d e f))
0 SPLIT-LIST > ((A B C D E F))
  1 SPLIT-LIST > ((B C D E F))
    2 SPLIT-LIST > ((C D E F))
      3 SPLIT-LIST > ((D E F))
        4 SPLIT-LIST > ((E F))
          5 SPLIT-LIST > ((F))
            6 SPLIT-LIST > (NIL)
            6 SPLIT-LIST < (NIL NIL)
          5 SPLIT-LIST < ((F) NIL)
        4 SPLIT-LIST < ((E) (F))
      3 SPLIT-LIST < ((D F) (E))
    2 SPLIT-LIST < ((C E) (D F))
  1 SPLIT-LIST < ((B D F) (C E))
0 SPLIT-LIST < ((A C E) (B D F))
(A C E)
(B D F)
```

Comment: Thank you sir! I always get trouble with the bottom half part of the recursion. First half which is getting rid of elements is easy but bottom half. Its little confusing. Great explanation though.